Remote debugging with Visual Studio and Conan 2.0
I am in the process of upgrading a CMake project to use Conan 2.0 for handling the libraries. We mostly build for windows but our CI system also compiles the code for Linux.
To help with Linux build issues we use a remote Linux server (Ubuntu 20.04) with Visual Studio 2017 or 2022. This was done by using a CMakePresets.json file to enable building on our remote Linux server.
I have noticed that after I have run conan install a CMakeUserPresets.json file is created. Can this be used to enable remote building and do I need any special options when running conan install to enable this?
